# How to compute the matrix $S$ in Sylvester's law of inertia

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

[Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) states that for any symmetric matrix $A$ there exist an invertible matrix S such that, $S^T A S = D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix which has only entries 0, +1 and −1 along the diagonal.

How can the matrix $S$ be computed such that for symmetric positive diagonal matrix $A$, the diagonal matrix $D$ will be in the following form, $\begin{pmatrix}
  I_r  \\
   &  0\\
  & & \ddots &  \\
   &   & & & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$.

Where $r = \text{rank} (A)$

Comment: start with these three; it is easy enough to adjust the resulting diagonal matrix to one with only $0,\pm1$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1392600#1392600 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388281/find-the-transitional-matrix-that-would-transform-this-form-to-a-diagonal-form/1391117#1391117

Comment: oh, if it really is positive semidefinite, I think there is a variant of Cholesky to do that.

Answer (score 4):

By the Spectral Theorem, $A$ is orthogonally similar to a diagonal matrix, i.e
$$
P^{T}AP=\pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n}
$$
where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and $\space P^{T}P=P^{-1}P=I$.
Since
$$
\pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n}=Q\pmatrix{I_r\\ &-I_s\\ && 0}Q
$$
where $r$ is the number of positive eigenvalues and $s$ the number of negative eigenvalues. $\lambda_i> 0, \:i\leqslant r,\:\lambda_i< 0,\:r<i\leqslant r+s$ and $\lambda_i= 0, \:i>r+s$. And
$$
Q=\pmatrix{{\sqrt{|\lambda_1|}} \\ & \ddots \\ && {\sqrt{|\lambda_{r+s}|}} \\ &&& 1} 
$$
And $Q^T=Q$. Let $S=PQ^{-1}$. Then
$$
S^TAS=\pmatrix{I_r\\ &-I_s\\ && 0}
$$

Comment: if we do not insist on orthogonality, it is quite easy. If integer entries, we may find $P$ with all coefficients rational, determinant one, and the whole thing algorithmic. Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1392600#1392600 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388281/find-the-transitional-matrix-that-would-transform-this-form-to-a-diagonal-form/1391117#1391117