# Transform $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=2{x_1}^2+5{x_2}^2+5{x_3}^2+4x_1x_2-4x_1x_3-8x_2x_3$ to a diagonal form.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, completing-the-square

I try to transform Transform $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=2{x_1}^2+5{x_2}^2+5{x_3}^2+4x_1x_2-4x_1x_3-8x_2x_3$$ to a diagonal form. I can do it using eigenvalue, but when I directly complete the square to find its diagonal form, I failed. And my textbook tell me that every formula like this can be transformed into diagonal form by completing the square. 
I have been working this for hours, please help me.

Comment: Show us what you've been trying.

Comment: But, it's already a quadratic form, isn't it?

Comment: Take a look at these: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329304/bilinear-form-diagonalisation  (user1551)
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1392600#1392600 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388281/find-the-transitional-matrix-that-would-transform-this-form-to-a-diagonal-form/1391117#1391117

Comment: @CameronBuie, most likely wants a diagonal form. The easy way is Hermite's, but recently a cookie-cutter method has been appearing on MSE, see the links in my previous comment.

Comment: @Kaster I try to complete the square of $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=2{x_1}^2+5{x_2}^2+5{x_3}^2+4x_1x_2-4x_1x_3-8x_2x_3$. And I can't find a proper substitution to complete it. This is I have been working with.

Comment: @Rowan what I meant is post your steps, and we might point out the mistake, rather than writing it down from scratch.

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry, I want a diagonal form. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every book on quadratic forms has Hermite's method in one or another disguise. It is easy. First we take care of all terms that contain $x_1.$

$$ 2 (x_1 + x_2 - x_3)^2 = 2 x_1^2 + 2 x_2^2 + 2 x_3^2 - 4 x_2 x_3 -4 x_3 x_1 + 4 x_1 x_2.   $$

$$   f - 2 (x_1 + x_2 - x_3)^2 = 3 x_2^2  - 4 x_2 x_3 + 3 x_3^2$$
Next we take care of all remaining terms that contain $x_2.$

$$  3 \left(x_2 - \frac{2}{3} x_3 \right)^2 = 3 x_2^2 - 4 x_2 x_3 + \frac{4}{3} x_3^2$$
$$   f - 2 (x_1 + x_2 - x_3)^2 -  3 \left(x_2 - \frac{2}{3} x_3 \right)^2 = \frac{5}{3} x_3^2  $$
As you see, all that is left involves only $x_3$ and is (must be) a multiple of $x_3^2.$
$$   f = 2 (x_1 + x_2 - x_3)^2 +  3 \left(x_2 - \frac{2}{3} x_3 \right)^2 + \frac{5}{3} x_3^2  $$

Comment: Start with all terms start with$x_1$ and do it again and again. Does this always work? Actually, Cameron's answer is complicated but more reasonable to me. But your answer is the one that  I can handle. And thanks for posting links related to this question. It's quite useful :)

Comment: @Rowan, the main extra step, not needed for your question, is when all that is left (no explicit squares) is of type $xy$ or, for ease, $4 xy.$ Here we use the trick $(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2 = 4xy $

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
2x_1^2 + 5x_2^2+5x_3^2 + 4x_1x_2-4x_1x_3-8x_2x_3 = \\
2\left( x_1^2+2x_1x_2-2x_1x_3-2x_2x_3\right) + 5x_2^2+5x_3^2 - 4x_2x_3 = \\
2 \left( x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + 2x_1x_2 - 2x_1x_3 - 2x_2x_3\right) + 3x_2^2 + 3x_3^2 - 4x_2x_3 = \\
2(x_1 + x_2 - x_3)^2 + 3 \left (x_2^2 - \frac 43 x_2x_3 + \frac 49 x_3^2 \right ) - \frac 43 x_3^2 + 3x_3^2 = \\
2\left( x_1 + x_2 - x_3\right)^2 + 3 \left( x_2  - \frac 23 x_3\right )^2 + \frac 53 x_3^2
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Kaster. What I have been trying is similar to BolzWeir's answer. I don't put $x_1,x_2,x_3$ together, so I failed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but we can note that $$2x_1^2+4x_1x_2-4x_1x_3=2x_1(x_1+2(x_2-x_3)),$$ which we can instead write as $$2(x_1+(x_2-x_3)-(x_2-x_3))(x_1+(x_2-x_3)+(x_2-x_3)),$$ or as $$2(x_1+x_2-x_3-(x_2-x_3))(x_1+x_2-x_3+(x_2-x_3)).$$ Applying the difference of squares formula and distributing the $2$ yields $$2(x_1+x_2-x_3)^2-2(x_2-x_3)^2=2(x_1+x_2-x_3)^2-2x_2^2-2x_3^2+4x_2x_3.$$ Hence, by substitution and gathering like terms, we have $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=2(x_1+x_2-x_3)^2+3x_2^2-4x_2x_3+3x_3^2.$$ Note that from this point, we could apply yet another instance of the difference of squares formula in the other direction, and obtain a factorization of $f.$ However, I suspect that instead, you'd rather observe that $3x_2^2-4x_2x_3$ can be rewritten (in a similar fashion to the work above) as $$3\left(x_2-\frac23x_3+\frac23x_3\right)\left(x_2-\frac23x_3-\frac23x_3\right),$$ whence we can show (again, similarly to the work above) that $$3x_2^2-4x_2x_3=3\left(x_2-\frac23x_3\right)^2-\frac43x_3^2,$$ and so $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=2(x_1+x_2-x_3)^2+3\left(x_2-\frac23x_3\right)^2+\frac53x_3^2.$$ Finally, putting $$\bar x_1=\sqrt2(x_1+x_2-x_3),\\\bar x_2=\sqrt3\left(x_2-\frac23x_3\right),\\\bar x_3=\sqrt{\frac53}x_3,$$ we have $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\bar x_1^2+\bar x_2^2+\bar x_3^2.$$

So, there you have it. Completing the square *does* allow us to rewrite it in the desired fashion. However, it's rather tedious, and it's far more preferable to use slicker, quicker tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about the Gaussian method? It goes like this:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 2\left[x_1^2 + \frac52 x_2^2 + \frac52 x_3^2 + 2x_1x_2 - 2x_1 x_3 - 8x_2 x_3 \right] \\ =2\left[ (x_1 ^2 + 2x_1x_2 \color{red}{+ x_2^2}) \color{red} {- x_2^2} + \frac52x_2^2 + \frac52x_3^2 - 2x_1x_3 -8x_2x_3 \right] \\ = 2\left[ (x_1 + x_2)^2 + ...\right]$$

You keep on doing that, and eventually put: $y_1 = x_1 + x_2$, etc.

Comment: This is what I want to do. But there are always some items can not be eliminated.