# If $\operatorname{in}(A) = (3,0,0)$ then the quadratic is an ellipsoid.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F(x,y,z)=2x^2+3y^2+5z^2-xy-xz-yz$ and

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\-\frac{1}{2} & 3 & -\frac{1}{2} \\-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 5\end{pmatrix}$ be the associated matrix.

The inertia of $A$, denoted $\operatorname{in}(A)$, is defined as the triple

$\operatorname{in}(A):=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$

where $n_i, i=1,2,3$ denoted the number of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues of $A$ respectively. Prove the following:

$i)$ If $\operatorname{in}(A) = (3,0,0)$ then the quadratic is an ellipsoid.

so this problem is saying it has 3 positive eigenvalues and no negative and no zero eigenvalues.

i know the general equation for an ellipsoid is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ and that it only makes since for the eigenvalues to be all positive.

i'm not too sure how to actually "prove" it other than the fact if it was a negative it'd be a different shape

Comment: You provide a lot of context, which is great.  However, it's not totally clear what you're asking.  Are you asking something like "how can I prove that a quadratic is an ellipsoid iff the associate matrix is positive definite"? Or, are you asking how to show that this *particular* quadratic is an ellipsoid (i.e. how to show that *this* matrix is positive definite)?

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to ask.

Comment: The first one or the second one?

Comment: the first one, sorry i didnt see the second part.

Comment: For the second part: it's easy to see that this matrix is positive definite since it is symmetric and [strictly diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) with positive diagonal entries.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388326/diagonal-matrix-a

Comment: same matrix with really good answer on how to send to congruent diagonal, typeset by another user   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388281/find-the-transitional-matrix-that-would-transform-this-form-to-a-diagonal-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$. Note that $F(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x^TAx$.

Now, by Sylvester's law of inertia: if $A$ is positive definite, there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that
$$
A = S^T\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1} S = S^TS
$$
Or in other words, we have
$$
F(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x^TS^TSx = (Sx)^T(Sx)
$$
Now, what does this mean geometrically? Let $s_{ij}$ denote the entries of $S$.  Let $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)^T = Sx$, so that
$$
\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\y_3} := S \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = 
\pmatrix{s_{11}x_1 + s_{12}x_2 + s_{13}x_3\\
s_{21}x_1 + s_{22}x_2 + s_{23}x_3\\
s_{31}x_1 + s_{32}x_2 + s_{33}x_3}
$$
We can think of this as a change of variables from $x$ to $y(x)$.  What we have, then, is that
$$
F(x_1,x_2,x_3) = y^Ty = y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2
$$
That is, there is a linear change of variables that takes us from this quadratic to the sphere.  That can only be true if we have an ellipsoid.

Comment: really good presentation of ***non-orthogonal*** diagonalization of the same matrix (same person asked), sometimes called finding a congruent diagonal matrix (and answers the inertia question) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388281/find-the-transitional-matrix-that-would-transform-this-form-to-a-diagonal-form/1388381#1388381

Comment: I typeset a different such problem, including matrices, at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr/1392111#1392111