# How to diagonalizable a matrix using congruence

Tags: linear-algebra

I learned now about how to diagonalize a symmetric matrices using congruence

for example I saw that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ so that

$P\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 0 & 6\\
  0 & 0 & 1\\
  6 & 1 & 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}P^{t}=\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -11 & 0\\
  0 & 0 &  (1/11)  \\
  \end{pmatrix}$

But how can I diagonalize this symmetric matrix using congruence

$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1\\
  1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}$

How can I find this $P$ according to the algorithm.

I would have link the algorithm if I would find it in the Net but I am sure you know what I am talking about.

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: In order to diagonalize this matrix, you would need a $P$ with entries that are complex numbers.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why? It's a real symmetric matrix. $P = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ should do the trick.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why? The OP is talking about diagonalisation by congruence, not diagonalisation by similarity. That is, he/she is trying to diagonalise a symmetric bilinear form but not a linear operator. As long as the characteristic of the ground field is not $2$, this is always possible over the same field, not to mention that the matrix in question is *real symmetric*, so that even the usual orthogonal diagonalisation works.

Comment: Ah whoops. Didn't read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You may first borrow some nonzero numbers from other off-diagonal entries. For example, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422601/how-to-diagonalize-fx-y-z-xyyzxz/422633#422633) to another question.

Comment: As you say in your title, I am often hot to solve a problem, but I rarely say so in public.

Comment: @martycohen Huh? What do you mean? Did you type your comment in a wrong thread?